# Why is QBittorrent not finding any DHT nodes?

Tags: settings, qbittorrent

I am having issues with connectivity for Qbittorrent 3.1.11 on Ubuntu 14.04. To be more specific, no matter what setting I attempt to use to download, none work. I constantly see no DHT nodes.